# Formula 1 and Betting vocabulary question

Tags: vocabulary, terminology

I don't get those [bets on a website betting on Formula 1](https://www.bet365.com/#/AC/B10/C20767865/D1/E65047373/F2/).
It is written that the qualifying winner of the next Russian GP in Formula 1 (26th september 2021) will have:

- **under** 0.1s winning margin with decimal odds 3.00
- between 0.1s and 0.25s inclusive winning margin with odds 3.5
- **over** 0.25s with 2.00

What is strange to me is the use of "under" and "over". I would have switch them. Because I understand "under 0.1s" as "less than 0.1s", or anything between 0 and 0.1s.

Maybe it is because I am French and in French we would say "Plus de 0.1s d'avance sur le deuxième" and would lead to "over".

Could you explain?

(Click on image to zoom)
[image]

Comment: "Over" and "under" have special meanings in sports betting. You have to understand how the bets are structured for it to make sense.

Comment: I don't understand this *at all*. Whatever "under/over NN secs winning margin" means, I can't imagine how it could make sense for the ***most extreme*** betting odds (3.5) to apply to the ***middle*** range of possible winning margins. Perhaps I just don't know enough about F1 racing. I do understand that it makes sense for the payour odds of throwing two dice with a total of 2 (2 x 1) or 12 (2 x 6) should be much higher than if the total is 7 (because there are more permutations of two dice that can give that total). But I can't conceptualise anything like that for F1 race times.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This might help... I didn't have time to do more than skim it, so apologies in advance if it doesn't. https://www.oddsshark.com/sports-betting/over-under-betting

Comment: Perhaps the over/under/betting confusions have led to translation confusions. Mais ouis, "**Plus de** 0.1s d'avance sur le deuxième" would be a "margin of **over** 0.1s." A margin "under" 0.1 would mean that the winner was less than 0.1s faster than the second place.

Comment: @ColleenV: Nah - that link is about betting that the grand total points (goals, or whatever) will be under or over some "target" arbitrarily chosen by the bookies. This one seems to be about betting on the race time difference between winner and second place - where apparently the odds favour that "winning margin" being less than 0.1sec rather than somewhere between 0.1sec and 0.25sec.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This is why pictures of text in a question are bad - it looked at a glance without my reading glasses like over/under to me. Also, haste makes waste :)

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to see exactly what the problem is here unless it is a translation problem. The question is what the margin of victory will be between first and second. It has been divided into three categories

> 0 to 0.1 seconds not including 0.1
> 0.1 seconds to 0.25 seconds including both end points
> 0.25 to infinity seconds not including 0.25

So for the first category we would normally say it as *under 0.1* or if we wanted to include the endpoint *0.1 and under* and similarly with *over* for the third category.

In technical writing and speech especially in mathematics we would probably use *less than* or *less than or equal to* or equivalent symbols.

Comment: I don't agree with your answer because to me the first category is that the margin is between infinity and 0.1s... Two of the categories can't happen at the same time